# Parsing GST timezone with datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse a `str` as a `datetime.datetime` object. However, I am unable to achieve this because the timezone is `GST`.

```
import datetime

s_dt = 'Mon Jul 01 17:17:37 UTC'
datetime.datetime.strptime(s_dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z')
# datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 1, 17, 17, 37)

s_dt = 'Mon Jul 01 17:17:37 GST'
datetime.datetime.strptime(s_dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z')
# ValueError: time data 'Mon Jul 01 17:17:37 GST' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to deal with this:-

1. Replace the GST in the string, to UTC
2. Replace the GST in the string, to UTC with proper time conversion (decreasing the time in UTC by 4 hours, as time GST is **+4 hours** from UTC).

**METHOD 1:-**

```
s_dt = 'Mon Jul 01 17:17:37 GST'.replace("GST", "UTC")

datetime.datetime.strptime(s_dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

**METHOD 2:-**

```
# replacing GST to UTC in original string
s_dt = 'Mon Jul 01 17:17:37 GST'.replace("GST", "UTC")

# getting the hours from the string
s_dt_obj = int(s_dt.split(":")[0][-2:])

# substracting 4 from the hours (in order to create UTC equivalent of GST time)
s_dt_obj = str((s_dt_obj - 4) % 24)

# putting everything back to a string
s_dt_obj = f"{s_dt.split(':')[0][:-2]}{s_dt_obj}:{s_dt.split(':')[1]}:{s_dt.split(':')[2]}"

# creating datetime object out of our newly created string
datetime.datetime.strptime(s_dt_obj, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z')
# datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 1, 13, 17, 37)
```